# Is it safe to rm /dev/wmi/dell-smbios?

Tags: linux, rhel7

I'm going though the STIG process on a RHEL 7.7 machine and ran across this finding:
https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/red_hat_enterprise_linux_7/2018-11-28/finding/V-72039

```
[root@localhost scripts]# find /dev -context *:device_t:* \( -type c -o -type b \) -printf "%p %Z\n"
/dev/wmi/dell-smbios system_u:object_r:device_t:s0
[root@localhost scripts]# find /dev -context *:unlabeled_t:* \( -type c -o -type b \) -printf "%p %Z\n"
[root@localhost scripts]# rpm -qf /dev/wmi/dell-smbios
file /dev/wmi/dell-smbios is not owned by any package
[root@localhost scripts]# ls -al /dev/wmi/dell-smbios
cr--r--r--. 1 root root 10, 57 May 19 11:29 /dev/wmi/dell-smbios
```

I am thinking of just deleting the device file but just don't know enough to be safe.

Comment: in case of a vm, snapshot it and then run a copy of it and try?

Comment: Not a VM. That was my plan though sort of. If no one has a clear answer then I will delete it as the last step. I'm building a script to config these machines as I go so it won't be a major loss if I kill the machine near the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go ahead and delete it. It's a [dev filesystem](https://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/dev.html), not a real file. Linux will either allow you to delete it or it won't, in any case it will reappear after the next reboot.

Comment: I forgot to come back and answer my own question but this is absolutely the correct answer.